# Jackson Xml: How to add namespace only on root?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

If i declare the namespace on the root element, like this:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(namespace = "urn:stackify:jacksonxml", localName = "PersonData")
public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String note;
}
```

It produces:

```
<PersonData xmlns="urn:stackify:jacksonxml">
    <id xmlns="">12345</id>
    <name xmlns="">Graham</name>
    <note xmlns="">Hello</note>
</PersonData>
```

But I want the namespace only on the root element. The xmlns attribute should not appear on child elements.

How can i archive this?

Answer (score 12):

There is a workaround which I found more elegant for me.

You may define constant for your namespace like this:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "PersonData")
public class Person {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private final String xmlns = "urn:stackify:jacksonxml";

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String note;
}
```

Comment: +1. That's a clever hack. It creates an attribute called `xmlns` and sets it to a value. Parsers are happy with the output. However this does not define a namespace in a way that would be understood by other frameworks working with xml and your classes, JAXB for example.

Comment: xmlns is not an attribute but namespace definition

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify the same namespace as the root element in each attribute:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(namespace = "urn:stackify:jacksonxml", localName = "PersonData")
public class Person {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "urn:stackify:jacksonxml")
    private String id;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "urn:stackify:jacksonxml")
    private String name;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "urn:stackify:jacksonxml")
    private String note;
}
```

Its a bit tiresome, but its the only way I found to avoid the unnecessary namespaces.

Comment: "You need"? Why? XML is happy using the namespace declared in the root element for all elements. Isn't this a bug in Jackson?

Answer (score 1):

Also works well with immutables library and json annotations (if you need to serialize/deserialize both in JSON and in XML)

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonRootName(value = "PersonData", namespace = "urn:stackify:jacksonxml")
public interface Person extends Serializable {

}
```